# How to get rid of the brightness popup screen

Tags: display, monitor, brightness, screen-brightness

The brightness pop up screen keeps appearing on my screen its stuck on there, I tried updating my software its all up to date, Any solutions. When I change the brightness percent it keeps on moving to maximum 100% even though I decrease it to minimum

I have tried to exit it via the monitor menu it just move up and it does not give me the option to exit the brightness box

Please see attached image

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try turn off the monitor and then turn it on again

Comment: I tried that, it does not work

Comment: Is there any hard button on the right side of the monitor corresponding to the symbol `X` (I think it's exit button) on the screen?